# Is it possible to use Bazel without compiling protobuf compiler?

Tags: protocol-buffers, gitlab-ci, bazel, protoc, bazel-rules

I have some projects using Bazel, C++ and protobuf. I also use gitlab CI/CD to build, test, check coverage, etc.

The problem is that when the project compiles first time it also compiles a protobuf compiler, which adds about 15 minutes to each step (the step itself takes 1-5 min).

I was using a setup example from this documentation:
https://blog.bazel.build/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html

Here I created [a simple hello world example with protobuf](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-protobuf-compile).
When I use `protoc` to generate `*.pb.cc`, `*.pb.h` files it takes about 5 seconds.
When I use `bazel build ...` it takes [15 minutes](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-protobuf-compile/-/raw/main/screenshot_build_time.png), because it builds protobuf compiler.

Build log: https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-protobuf-compile/-/jobs/1532045913

### Main Question

Is there any other way to setup Bazel to use already precompiled `protoc` and to skip 15 min on every step?

#### Update 2021-08-27

Added overwriting `proto_compiler` and `proto_toolchain_for_cc` as described in [Implicit Dependencies and Proto Toolchains](https://blog.bazel.build/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html#implicit-dependencies-and-proto-toolchains)

Building `:person_proto` now works fine

```sh
$ bazel build :person_proto
WARNING: Ignoring JAVA_HOME, because it must point to a JDK, not a JRE.
INFO: Analyzed target //:person_proto (19 packages loaded, 61 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:person_proto up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/person_proto-descriptor-set.proto.bin
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.428s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 5 processes: 4 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
```

but building `:person_cc_proto` fails

```sh
$ bazel build :person_cc_proto
WARNING: Ignoring JAVA_HOME, because it must point to a JDK, not a JRE.
ERROR: /home/m/Synology/drive/prog/2021/b/issue-bazel-protobuf-compile/BUILD:2:14: in :aspect_cc_proto_toolchain attribute of BazelCcProtoAspect aspect on proto_library rule //:person_proto: '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not have mandatory providers: ProtoLangToolchainProvider
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:person_cc_proto' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//:person_proto' failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.124s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 25 targets configured)
```

Comment: From the list of [dependencies](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/blob/master/proto/private/dependencies.bzl), it seems to me that the `protobuf_rule` uses a precompiled binary when it is available for the host architecture.

Comment: In any case, you should set up a blaze remote cache, so that build artefacts are reused between CI invocations.

Answer (score 0):

From https://blog.bazel.build/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html#implicit-dependencies-and-proto-toolchains

> The `proto_library` rule implicitly depends on `@com_google_protobuf//:protoc`, which is the protocol buffer compiler. It must be a binary rule (in protobuf, it's a `cc_binary`). The rule can be overridden using the `--proto_compiler` command-line flag.

Hence, you could (not tested)

1. add the precompiled binary in your workspace,
2. define a [`cc_import`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_import) for this target
3. pass the `--proto_compiler` command-line flag

Comment: I used github.com/google/startup-os as example, binded `proto_compiler` and was able to build `:person_proto`, but the next step still fails when I try to build `:person_cc_proto` with `every rule of type proto_library implicitly depends upon the target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_toolchain'...`

here are my changes in `dev` branch: https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-protobuf-compile/-/tree/dev

Comment: I have overridden `protoc` and `:person_proto` is compiled successfully. Unfortunately building `:person_cc_proto` fails. Added an update to original post with more details. Could you please take a look?

Comment: From the error, the provided toolchain is not proto lang tool chain… Sounds like you wrote the toolchain yourself, and made a mistake there.